# Run time error 13 Type mismatch in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have dates in different formats in a column. I am trying to convert into the format `11.01.2019`. These dates are coming from body of the emails so these are in string format.
This is my code which works for few of them but not for all of them. I am trying to add the conditional requirements for all formats of the dates.

[image]

```
Sub ConvertToDate()

  Dim r As Range
  Dim setdate As Range

  Set setdate = Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(3, 3).End(xlDown))

  With setdate
    .NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy" 
    .Value = .Value
  End With

  For Each r In setdate
      r.Value = CDate(r.Value)
  Next r

End Sub
```

The error is shown in the line:

```
r.Value = CDate(r.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your values with dates in Excel. If they are automatically aligned to the left, Excel does not consider them dates, but Strings. On the picture below, column A and column B are strings and column C is a date.

[image]

When `r.Value = CDate(r.Value)` is applied to a String, the type mismatch error comes, because VBA does not know how to convert the string to a date.

To make sure, that the date is formatted as a date, and Excel knows what to do with it, you have to find a way to parse `1-Mar-19` to a date. There are a few ways to do it, depending on how you feel like it. Probably the easiest is to replace `-` with `/` and leave VBA and Excel to do the rest:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim r As Range        
    For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:B9")
        r = Replace(r, "-", "/")
        r.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: An error in OP *possibly* occurs already in the first line assuming the caption to be included into the setdate range. If so it could help to resize the range and start the loop by `For Each r In setdate.Offset(1).Resize(setdate.Rows.Count - 1, 1)`

Comment: @Vityata it doesn't  work for me. The signs have been changed but the date remains same.

Comment: @mak - you want to change the date and not the format?

Comment: @T.M. after adding this line I have Run Time error 1004. Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: @mak - which line? Simply try to replicate the code in my answer, it should work. In general, what are your regional settings?

Comment: @mak - using your original setdate definition you'll have to ensure that there *are* actually data after cell `C3`, otherwise you are including the last possible row where an Offset of +1 results in an impossible address.  I assume you *have* data in your source sheet, but you didn't identify this sheet by a fully qualified range reference, e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Range(...)`. If so your `setdate` object always refers to the currently *active* workbooks, where you possibly have no data in column after `C3`...

Comment: @T.M. - I was working with one Workbook only, thus the fully qualified reference was enough for me :) Still, added `ThisWorkbook` to the reference.

Comment: @Vityata your code works but it only help to remove `-´ and put / instead but not more to change it to values. I briefly summarized the problem again.

Comment: @mak - what do you mean by "changeit to values"? Do you still get the error with the input from the screenshot?

Comment: @Vityata it means it remains the same even with excel format cells I am unable to change it to required format and i have same error.

Comment: @mak - did you format the alignment to the right manually on the screenshot? Or is it naturally to the right, after writing them?

Comment: @Vityata sorry they are aligned naturally.

Comment: @mak - If you align manually, it does not help to convert to date. Can you open a new Excel file, write the dates and see how they are formatted? Without aligning to manually.